# Azure Boards unable to add users

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

We have Azure DevOps portal for our organization and our Active Directory is connected to it. I have enough privileges to add new users to the DevOps portal.
Recently I have seen that whenever I am trying to add new users I am getting the below error:
[image]

The user is added to the AAD. He is an active user and belongs to the same organization. I have cleared the cache and tested it.
Still, I am unable to add the user because of the issue.
Is there anything that I can do to rectify this, before approaching the support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are trying to invite a use from outside your directory. ...

To solve this issue, you need to grant the **Guest Inviter role**  to your account in Azure AD(Active Directory).

You could navigate to **Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Roles and administrators -> Search Guest Inviter**.

[image]

Then you could assign the Guest Inviter role to your account.

In this case, you could invite the user successfully.

For more detailed info , you could refer to this doc about [Add external users to your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-external-user?view=azure-devops).

Comment: I believe this could fix the issue. We have contacted the administrator to apply the changes. I will update as soon as this is fixed. However, I am not sure how it worked earlier. I never got this error earlier.

Comment: @Asterix. Feel free to let me know the result. If the method could help you resolve this issue, you may consider accepting it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: thank you so much. I wasn't earlier added to the AAD. When they synced the Azure AAD with Devops, I was added there with lesser privileges. it somehow overrode my existing admin privileges in DevOps. Now with guest inviter privilege, I can add users again. Thank you for this information

Answer (score 0):

It's been a couple of hours since your question posted. Does it work now? Your statement that the user is in your AAD, plus the error message that the user is outside your directory, suggests the possibility that maybe waiting might fix it.

Comment: Hi, the issue has been there since past few weeks. Stil not got fixed .